# Add a filter to a large mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this large query, and I just need to filter out any results where the `tbl_dealinterest.Active`  = `'n'`.  There sometimes isn't an entry in that table for the product, and sometimes it might there might be and entry and set to y.

Here is the large ugly query:

```
SELECT tbl_product.id, tbl_productspecification.id AS specificationId,
                        tbl_product.ProductId, tbl_seller.CompanyName, tbl_product.ProductName, tbl_product.Description, mst_Categories.id AS 'Category',
                        tbl_productspecification.RetailPrice, tbl_productspecification.SalePrice,
                        tbl_product.image, tbl_productspecification.Discount, tbl_product.EndTime, tbl_product.Seller_Id, tbl_dealinterest.Active AS thumbsActive
                        FROM tbl_product
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_seller ON tbl_seller.SelId = tbl_product.Seller_Id
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_Categories ON (mst_Categories.id = tbl_product.Category OR mst_Categories.id = tbl_product.SubCategory)
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_productspecification ON tbl_productspecification.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN mst_image ON mst_image.Product = tbl_product.ProductId
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_dealinterest ON tbl_dealinterest.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId AND tbl_dealinterest.BuyerId = '$token' 
                        WHERE tbl_product.Active='y'
                        AND tbl_product.StartTime <= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'
                        AND tbl_product.EndTime > '".date("Y-m-d")." 06:00:00'
                        ".$subquery."
                        GROUP BY tbl_productspecification.ProductId";
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What is your problem with the current query?

Comment: There is a no problem, it just needs to be extended to exclude some items.

Comment: When I addded popnoodles suggestion, the same results were returned, but the Active fields were just empty.  No 'n' anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
WHERE tbl_product.Active='y'
AND (tbl_dealinterest.Active <> 'n' OR tbl_dealinterest.Active IS NULL)
...
```

Comment: I added this and it returns only results that tbl_dealinterest.Active is set to 'n'.  I reversed it, and no results were returned.  Crazy

Comment: Thats works.  Thanks alot for helping my unclear description...  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_dealinterest ON (tbl_dealinterest.ProductId = tbl_product.ProductId 
    AND tbl_dealinterest.BuyerId = '$token' 
    AND tbl_dealinterest.Active<>'n')
```

Comment: I just tried this and it returns the same values, and the Active fields are all just empty

Comment: so you don't want that are null either

Comment: Yes, I wish I could've explained it better.